# Map soap response to object

Tags: android, xml, jackson, mapping, android-ksoap2

I have this problem for 3 days. He gets the following response from the server

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><ns2:getTasks xmlns:ns2="????">
<task>
    <id>25688</id>
    <code>53474/CI/10/1</code>
    <stateCode>allocated</stateCode>
    <commissionCode>53474/CI/10</commissionCode>
    <commissionId>23695</commissionId>
    <commisionRegistration>2022-09-08T10:02:59.723+02:00</commisionRegistration>
    <plannedRealizationFrom>2022-10-07T09:30:00.000+02:00</plannedRealizationFrom>
    <plannedRealizationTo>2022-10-07T11:30:00.000+02:00</plannedRealizationTo>
    <attachments>
        <attachment>
              <id>3580</id>
              <typeId>1004</typeId>
              <fileName>JPEG_20221017_143416_4079146694302606942.jpg</fileName>
            <dataPresent>false</dataPresent>
            <typeName>com.???.???.???.model.task.po.TaskAttachmentPo</typeName>
        </attachment>
    </attachments>
    <anotherObject>
    ???
    </anotherObject>
    <anotherObject>
     ???
    </anotherObject>
    <anotherObject>
    ???
    </anotherObject>

</task>
</ns2:getTasks></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I wanna map this into object taskMo. This class cointains others object like AttachmentMo, CommissionMo

```
public class TaskMo extends MobileTransferObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo
    protected Long id;

    @ColumnInfo
    protected String code;

    @TypeConverters(DatabaseConverter.class)
    protected TaskTypeMo type;

    @TypeConverters(DatabaseConverter.class)
    protected TaskState state;

    // TODO It's a hack, this table should be normalized in the near future
    @ColumnInfo
    protected String taskStateCode;

    @ColumnInfo
    protected String commissionCode;

    @ColumnInfo
    protected Long commissionId;

    @ColumnInfo
    protected String notRealizedCauseCode;

    @TypeConverters(DatabaseConverter.class)
    protected CommissionMo commission;

    @TypeConverters(DatabaseConverter.class)
    protected List<ResourceOperationMo> operations;

    @TypeConverters(DatabaseConverter.class)
    protected GregorianCalendar commissionRegistration;

    @TypeConverters(DatabaseConverter.class)
    protected GregorianCalendar plannedRealizationFrom;

    @TypeConverters(DatabaseConverter.class)
    protected GregorianCalendar plannedRealizationTo;

    @TypeConverters(DatabaseConverter.class)
    protected GregorianCalendar realizationFrom;

    @TypeConverters(DatabaseConverter.class)
    protected GregorianCalendar realizationTo;

    @ColumnInfo
    protected Integer realizationTime;

    @ColumnInfo
    protected String description;

    @ColumnInfo
    protected String notices;

    @ColumnInfo
    protected Integer driveTime;

    @ColumnInfo
    protected Double numberOfKilometers;

    @TypeConverters(DatabaseConverter.class)
    protected LocationMo location;

    @TypeConverters(DatabaseConverter.class)
    private List<AttachmentMo> attachments = new ArrayList<AttachmentMo>();

    @TypeConverters(DatabaseConverter.class)
    private List<AttributeGroupMo> attrGroups = new ArrayList<AttributeGroupMo>();

    @ColumnInfo
    private boolean moNotClearChanged = false;

    @ColumnInfo
    private boolean isIncorrectTaskExecutor = false;
}
```

I am currently using this to map the response to object

```
public TaskMo readTask(SoapObject x) {
    if (x == null) {
        return null;
    }

    TaskMo r = new TaskMo();

    r.setId(readWsLong(x, "id"));
    r.setCode(readWsString(x, "code"));
    r.setStateCode(readWsString(x, "stateCode"));
    r.setCommissionCode(readWsString(x, "commissionCode"));
    r.setCommissionId(readWsLong(x, "commissionId"));
    CommissionMo commission = readCommission(getPropertyAsSoapObjectSafely(x, "commission"));
    r.setCommission(commission);
    r.setType(readTaskType(getPropertyAsSoapObjectSafely(x, "taskType")));
    r.setNotRealizedCauseCode(readWsString(x, "notRealizedCauseCode"));
    r.setCommissionRegistration(readWsCalendar(x, "commissionRegistration"));
    r.setDescription(readWsString(x, "description"));
    r.setNotices(readWsString(x, "notices"));
    r.setRealizationFrom(readWsCalendar(x, "realizationFrom"));
    r.setRealizationTo(readWsCalendar(x, "realizationTo"));
    r.setRealizationTime(readWsInteger(x, "realizationTime"));
    r.setLocation(readLocation(x, "location"));
    r.setDriveTime(readWsInteger(x, "driveTime"));
    r.setNumberOfKilometers(readWsDouble(x, "numberOfKilometers"));

    SoapObject operationsSoapObject = getPropertyAsSoapObjectSafely(x, "operations");
    r.setOperations(getOperations(operationsSoapObject));

    SoapObject attributes = getPropertyAsSoapObjectSafely(x, "attributeGroups");
    if (attributes != null) {
        List<AttributeGroupMo> attrGroups = new ArrayList<AttributeGroupMo>();

        for (int i = 0; i < attributes.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
            SoapObject group = (SoapObject) attributes.getProperty(i);
            attrGroups.add(readAttributeGroup(group));
        }
        r.setAttrGroups(attrGroups);
    }

    r.setPlannedRealizationFrom(readWsCalendar(x, "plannedRealizationFrom"));
    r.setPlannedRealizationTo(readWsCalendar(x, "plannedRealizationTo"));

    SoapObject attachmentAttributes = getPropertyAsSoapObjectSafely(x, "attachments");
    if (attachmentAttributes != null) {
        List<AttachmentMo> attachments = new ArrayList<AttachmentMo>();

        for (int i = 0; i < attachmentAttributes.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
            SoapObject attachment = (SoapObject) attachmentAttributes.getProperty(i);
            attachments.add(readAttachment(attachment));
        }

        r.setAttachments(attachments);
    }

    r.moClearChanged();

    return r;
}
```

I would like to change this mechanism to something that will automatically create an object from the response (for example Jackson ObjectMapper)

```
httpTransport.call(getSoapActionPrefix() + method, envelope); // send request

Object result = envelope.getResponse(); // get response


    List<Map<String, String>> map = parseTest(httpTransport.responseDump, "task");

    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // jackson's objectmapper
  //  final TaskMo pojo = mapper.convertValue(map.toString(), TaskMo.class);
```

Im getting exception:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized field "commonName" (class com.softelnet.ksavi.android.model.TaskMo), not marked as ignorable (27 known properties: "commissionRegistration", "numberOfKilometers"....)`

CommonName is part of Object which cointains TaskMo

I would be very grateful for a hint on how to do this

Comment: Jackson should be able to handle that, or where is the problem?

Comment: Im getting exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized field "commonName" (class com.softelnet.ksavi.android.model.TaskMo), not marked as ignorable (27 known properties: "commissionRegistration", "numberOfKilometers"....)